# Can SDK contain Authorisation like 2FA

Tags: android, ios, architecture, sdk, frameworks

I'm building mobile SDK which will provide solution of Signing from private key, for these SDK communicating with server using APIs with Access token.

So for getting access token we need Authorisation from server, so my question is that according to standard will Authorisation will be part of SDK as Authorisation may include 2FA where OTPs dialogue show, or SDK only perform its core work and token may get from exposed methods

Comment: You would typically authenticate using an oauth flow. Any 2FA is then handled by the IDP

Comment: @Paulw11 So by this mean Authentication would be on SDK end ?